# How to import that root certificate as trusted root in Azure AppService?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, azure-appservice

Currently i am working on a project, where i need to validate the `.cer` version of the certificate.For every transaction User will upload a new `.cer` file. Below is my code

```
       public static bool IsValidCert(this MemoryStream cer)
        {
            using X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(cer.ToArray());
            return cert.Verify();
        }
```

So in local system, the certificates are getting validated properly(*currently using Self Signed Certificates*). So to make sure for each certificate to added to root used below code with `X509Store`

```
public static bool IsValidCert(this MemoryStream cer)
        {

            using X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(cer.ToArray());

            using X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(cert);
            store.Close();

            return cert.Verify();
        }
```

So its working for my local system. But when i am pushing the same piece of code to `Azure App service` ,Getting the below error:- `"Chain error: UntrustedRoot A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider."`.

Where is the issue i am not getting. In my local system the Certificate is there in the Trusted Root Certification Authority.

How to import that root certificate as trusted root in Azure?

**Use Case:-** i am using GraphAPI & i am creating a Client certificate for an AAD App. so User(already Authorized) will upload a certificate to create an AAD App. so i need to verify the Certificate is valid or not before pushing it to Graph API. Currently Using `X509Certificate2` to verify the certificate. so an Untrusted certificate (Self signed Certificate) is blocking me in App service.

Comment: As you have already started a discussion on MS Q&A, Posting the link here to help other community members: [How to import that root certificate as trusted root in Azure AppService?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/614251/how-to-import-that-root-certificate-as-trusted-roo.html)

Comment: You can refer to [Adding trust to root certificate store on an App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/107132/adding-trust-to-root-certificate-store-on-an-app-s.html) and [Root CA on App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/06/22/Root-CA-on-App-Service-Guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

App Service Front Ends doesn't do any certificate validations on the incoming client cert.

For App Service multi-tenant PaaS, adding/removing the trusted cert store of the machines is not supported. Currently adding root CAS is only supported for ASE (App Service Environment).
[ASE -private-client-certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/environment/certificates#private-client-certificate)

App Service is a service running on top of the Azure PaaS (platform as a service) infrastructure. App Service runs on a [sandboxed environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions) with restrictions to the underlying machine.

In App Service, TLS termination of the request happens at the frontend load balancer. When forwarding the request to your app code with client certificates enabled, App Service injects an `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header with the client certificate. App Service does not do anything with this client certificate other than forwarding it to your app. Your app code is responsible for validating the client certificate.

Also, please check the [samples](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth.md#accessing-the-client-certificate-from-your-web-app) and doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#access-client-certificate).

Comment: Hi Ajay, This not related to SSL Authentication. To be more precise,  i am using GraphAPI & i am creating a Client certificate for an AAD App. so User(already Authorized) will upload a certificate to create an AAD App. so i need to verify the Certificate is valid or not before pushing it to Graph API. Currently Using X509Certificate2 to verify the certificate. so an Untrusted certificate (Self signed Certificate) is blocking me in App service.

Comment: Thanks for sharing additional clarity. In the multi-tenant App service, you can’t modify the trusted root store due to sandbox restrictions. However, on ASE can you modify the trusted root store. 

App Service has a list of Trusted Root Certificates which you cannot modify in the multi-tenant variant version of App Service, but you can load your own CA certificate in the Trusted Root Store in an App Service Environment (ASE), which is a single-tenant environment in App Service. So, what you’re trying to accomplish won’t be possible without an ASE or cert signed by a trusted CA.

Comment: Kindly check this document for more details. 
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/06/22/Root-CA-on-App-Service-Guide.html

Azure Web App sandbox
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions 

Operating system functionality on Azure App Service
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#code-execution-processes-and-memory

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way for now in AppService to add it to root(except some of the default one those were added by MS) can be checked by the following command in Kudu.

```
dir cert:\localmachine\root
```

So to handle this scenario, have used this way. While using the `X509Chain` it will validate all the certificate validation along with `UntrustedRoot`. So we need to add some extra validation for this subcase(e.g. to check which  some fixed domain list) or need to allow the `UntrustedRoot` certificate. Code will look something like this

```
public static bool IsValidCert(this byte[] cer)
     {

            using X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(cer.ToArray());
            using X509Chain certChain = new X509Chain();
            certChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
            var result = certChain.Build(cert);


            if (!result && certChain.ChainStatus.Any(status => status.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
            {
                foreach (X509ChainStatus chainStatus in certChain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if (chainStatus.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
                    {
                      //Custom logic to handle the scenario  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //throw exception for the validation error
                    }
                }
                throw new exception();
            }
            return true;
        }
```